# react-hook-form not getting value, when value set based on select option value in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form validation for my project. I have a select option, when it change I set the value of selected one to another input which is customer but when I submit the form , customer value show empty, How to fix this issue ?

This is my code

```
function App() {
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState();
const [inputs1, setInputs1] = useState();

const {
register,
formState: { errors },
trigger,
handleSubmit
} = useForm({
defaultValues: {
  searchby: "searchby",
  customers: "",
  firstName: ""
  }
 });

const onSubmit = (data) => {
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
};

const handleInputChanges = (event) => {
const name = event.target.name;
const value = event.target.value;
 setInputs(value);
 setInputs1(value);
};

  return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <select
    name="searchby"
    {...register("searchby", {
      required: "password is required."
    })}
    value={inputs}
    onChange={handleInputChanges}
  >
    <option selected value="searchby">
      Search By
    </option>
    <option value="customerID">Custimer ID </option>
    <option value="teleco">Teleco</option>
  </select>
  {errors.searchby && <p>This field is Required</p>}
  <label>Customer: </label>
  <input
    name="customers"
    {...register("customers")}
    value={inputs1}
    onChange={handleInputChanges}
  />

  {errors.customers && <p>This field is Required</p>}

  <label>First name: </label>
  <input {...register("firstName", { required: true })} />
  {errors.firstName && <p>This field is Required</p>}

  <input type="submit" />
  <button
    type="button"
 
      >
    Validate All
     </button>
    </form>
  );
  }
```

This is what I am getting when I submit the form

[image]

Code link : [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-7gcizr?file=/src/index.js:0-1865)

Comment: In react-hook-form version 7.16.0 and above you can do like this: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/releases/tag/v7.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`register`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/) method provides `ref`, `value`, `onChange` and `onBlur` for your input, but you can use the second parameter to pass a custom `onChange` and use [`setValue`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue/) to update the `customers` input:

```
const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    trigger,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      searchby: "searchby",
      customers: "",
      firstName: ""
    }
  });

...


const handleInputChanges = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  setValue("customers", value);
};

...

<select
  name="searchby"
  {...register("searchby", {
    onChange: handleInputChanges,
    required: "password is required."
  })}
>
  <option selected value="searchby">
    Search By
  </option>
  <option value="customerID">Custimer ID </option>
  <option value="teleco">Teleco</option>
</select>
```

[image: Edit react-hook-form (forked)]

Comment: Thanks @Fraction for your answer, how if we call an API based on selection option and setValue to customer ?

Comment: Just call your API and set the value when it is resolved, ex `myAPI().then(res => setValue("customers", res));`, you can also use `async/await`

Answer (score 3):

When you using {...register('anyFieldName')} it will give your component react-hook-form's new created form-field values and handlers, for example value & onChange handler, and so on. When you use your own value & onChange handler it overrides react-hook-form's given form-field value & onChange handler.

You can learn more about register [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register)

Try like this

```
 <input
  name="customers"
  {...register("customers")} 
/>
```

*I would recommend use `useController` hook, because it is more flexible than `register`.
With `register` your component is not controlled by your own.*

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing both classic component handling and `react-hook-form` here.
We're going to rely on `react-hook-form` and go from there.

By looking at the Codesandbox, we will need to do the following changes:

- firstly, let's get rid of all the state used and all the `onChange` handlers used.
- let's change the `useForm()` invocation to this:

```
const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue,
    handleSubmit
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      searchby: "searchby",
      customers: "",
      firstName: ""
    }
  });
```

- now, we need to extract some of the functions that the `register()` gives us, in order to change a bit the `onChange` function

```
  const {onChange, ...rest} = register('searchby', {required: 'Password is required'})
```

- let's create an `onSelectChange` handler, that will be called every time the value of the select is changed

```
  const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    onChange(e);
    //change this to any value / logic you want
    setValue('customers', 'SomeValue')
  }
```

- now, what's left is to update the `<select/>`

```
      <select
        {...rest}
        onChange={handleSelectChange}
      >
        <option selected value="searchby">
          Search By
        </option>
        <option value="customerID">Custimer ID </option>
        <option value="teleco">Teleco</option>
      </select>
```

#### Fully assembled example:

```
function App() {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue,
    handleSubmit
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      searchby: "searchby",
      customers: "",
      firstName: ""
    }
  });

  const {onChange, ...rest} = register('searchby', {required: 'Password is required'})

  const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    onChange(e);
    //change this to any value / logic you want
    setValue('customers', 'SomeValue')
  }

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <select
        {...rest}
        onChange={handleSelectChange}
      >
        <option selected value="searchby">
          Search By
        </option>
        <option value="customerID">Custimer ID </option>
        <option value="teleco">Teleco</option>
      </select>
      {errors.searchby && <p>This field is Required</p>}
      <label>Customer: </label>
      <input
        name="customers"
        {...register("customers")}
      />

      {errors.customers && <p>This field is Required</p>}

      <label>First name: </label>
      <input {...register("firstName", { required: true })} />
      {errors.firstName && <p>This field is Required</p>}

      <input type="submit" />
      <button type="button">Validate All</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are setting the "customers" input value dynamically when selecting the "searchBy" select value. In this case the onChange event for "customers" will not be triggered. But will be triggered on typing value.

One of the solution will be adding the dynamically changed "customers" value at the time of onsubmit trigger without the help of react-use-form